# Is there a way to "extract" and detect concave point to fit ellipses?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-3.7, opencv

This paper seems very relevant to my problem but I can find the code online.

[Splitting touching cells based on concave points and ellipse fitting](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bwpuB5RDQqlelzIZCkuz2sO2q6LXGs4u/view?usp=sharing) as well.

I'm also trying to understand their algorithm. I'm stuck at finding the concave points of touching objects.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("binary_img.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh_img = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
thresh_img = 255- thresh_img
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_img,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

hull = []

# calculate points for each contour
for i in range(len(contours)):
    # creating convex hull object for each contour
    hull.append(cv2.convexHull(contours[i], False))

# create an empty black image
drawing = np.zeros((thresh_img.shape[0], thresh_img.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)

# draw contours and hull points
for i in range(len(contours)):
    color_contours = (0, 255, 0) # green - color for contours
    color = (255, 0, 0) # blue - color for convex hull
    # draw ith contour
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color_contours, 1, 8, hierarchy)
    # draw ith convex hull object
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, hull, i, color, 1, 8)

cv2.imwrite("19_drawing.png", drawing)
cv2.imshow("Drawing", drawing)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: binary image]

[image: Contours]

**AIM**:

I would like to get the concave points below and fit an ellipse. My code is simply wrapping the extremities.

Any help or direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: Goal]

Comment: check https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gada4437098113fd8683c932e0567f47ba

Answer (score 0):

First obvious point would be to explore Convex defects. The concave points are the defects of the convexHull so you could easilyu find them if you select the minimum ones.
Another direction would be to explore Fourier Descriptors and check the mapping between the actual points and their descriptors. The good thing about FD is that they are orientation and scale invariant.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).